# Sending commands from server side (.NET) to browser

Tags: javascript, .net, client-server, rpc, p2p

We have some web application that allows users login and do some work.
But sometimes users work with our web site opening more then one browser and this causes us a lot of problems.
How could we implement the following - on user log in to our web site, make automatic log out in all his previously logged in browsers?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but you should fix the problems caused by opening more than one browser rather than ignoring it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS localStorage on page load to detect a user login, the event will be fired on every tabs or window opened within the same domain :

```
function storageChange(event) {
    if(event.key == 'user_login') {

        // logout - except current window
    }
}
window.addEventListener('storage', storageChange, false);

//when user logs in
window.localStorage.setItem('user_login', true);
```

That will work only if the user is using the same browser multiple times.

Comment: Will this work also in the case when user logged in from different browsers?

Comment: Thank you but we need solution also for different browsers case.